# Grounding with a battery-powered differential amplifier

Tags: grounding

I have made a simple battery powered instrumentation amplifier (based on the AD8429 chip) for some very low noise measurements.
The rough circuit diagram is below.

[image: circuit]

Note that the BNC input is isolated from the enclosure, while the output BNC has its shield shorted to the enclosure.

I connect to a device under test, which is mains-powered and has some reference to ground, but I wish to make a differential measurement. I look at the output on a mains-powered scope. The cables are RG58 coax, and are no more than metre or two in length.

When I use the amplifier, if I just leave it connected as in the diagram, there is a lot more noise than I would think, mostly at few MHz. But, if I touch the aluminium enclosure with my finger, the noise goes away, and it's closer to what I expected.
This doesn't happen if I touch the bare metal connector of the coax connected to the scope.

Why does this happen? I have a theory, which is that since that the ground reference for the amplifier is coming through the coax shield, and the shield has a reasonably high resistance, current flowing along it gives a lot of voltage drop.

How best to fix this so I can make a low-noise measurement? Should I use a low-resistance connection between the enclosure and the scope?

Comment: "This doesn't happen if I touch the bare metal connector of the coax connected to the scope." - BUT you said "the output BNC has its shield shorted to the enclosure."

Comment: If I touch the end of the BNC cable connected to the enclosure, the noise drops. But I touch THE OTHER END of the same BNC cable (where its connected to the scope), nothing happens. Even though in principle these are the same circuit point.

Comment: You are acting as the capacitor of a low pass filter when you touch the case.  The case is picking up noise and probably capacitively coupling it to your circuit differentially or common-mode. (CMRR drops a lot at high frequencies.)  Therefore your box is not adequately grounded for high frequency signals.  Skin effect, inductance, contact resistance, etc. all work against you at higher frequencies.  Try a short flat copper braid between the box and the scope's ground or another solid ground. You may need to experiment to find the optimum configuration.